# Logging into iOS app with facebook produces "An error occurred. Please try again later" error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My iOS app was working completely fine until this afternoon when it suddenly started throwing this error:
"An error occurred. Please try again later"

When I go to the facebook page for the app, I get an "expired page" error. What seems to have happened to the app?